# Boost.MPI on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: c++, boost, ubuntu, mpi

### Background

Hi All,

I'm trying to use Boost::MPI, at the moment I'm just trying to run the simple first example from the [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/mpi/tutorial.html). I am having trouble building/running it.

I installed boost using apt-get and installed boost_mpi & boost_serialization (1.48.0) using synaptic package manager. I installed MPICH2 using apt-get.

Even though OpenMPI was never explicitly installed it appears to be on my system, I assume this is a dependency for Boost::MPI but it appears MPICH2 and OpenMPI are treading on each other's toes.

### Info

If I build using

```
g++ test.cpp -I/usr/include/mpich2 -L/usr/lib -lboost_mpi -lboost_serialization
```

then run using

```
mpiexec -n 2 ./a.out
```

It throws a bunch of errors which seem to come from OpenMPI. If I try and build by linking against the OpenMPI library using

```
g++ test.cpp -L/usr/lib -lboost_mpi -lboost_serialization -lmpi -I/usr/include/openmpi
```

I get the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccJ5ezv7.o: undefined reference to symbol 'ompi_op_set_cxx_callback'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'ompi_op_set_cxx_callback' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/libmpi.so.0 so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/libmpi.so.0: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
```

If I try building using `mpic++` with the following command

```
mpic++ test.cpp -lboost_mpi -lboost_serialization
```

It will not link returning a bunch of errors of the form

```
 /usr/lib/libmpich.so: undefined reference to `MPL_trid'
```

so I tried linking against libmpi i.e.

```
mpic++ test.cpp -lboost_mpi -lboost_serialization -lmpi
```

This builds but on running with `mpiexec` yields the following errors

```
Fatal error in PMPI_Errhandler_set: Invalid communicator, error stack:
PMPI_Errhandler_set(118): MPI_Errhandler_set(comm=0x370500, errh=0x370be0) failed
PMPI_Errhandler_set(70).: Invalid communicator
```

### Question

It seems to me that somehow OpenMPI and MPICH2 are getting intertwined where there really shouldn't. Does anybody know how I can build against only OpenMPI or MPICH2 then run using the correct `mpiexec`?

Comment: Can't you uninstall either openmpi or mpich?

Comment: I tried running `sudo apt-get remove mpich2` but it seemed to leave all of the library and include files on my system

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get purge mpich2`. `purge` will remove all files too.

Comment: @Dan Probably you need to remove libmpich too

Comment: Tried `sudo apt-get purge mpich2` and now it cannot locate `mpiexec`. And `apt-get` wont touch openmpi-dev because it thinks it's up to date.

Comment: Also, ideally I'd like to keep MPICH2 and OpenMPI both installed since another piece of software I use builds against MPICH2. (I'm assuming boost is stuck to OpenMPI)

Comment: mpic++ executable belongs to openmpi or mpich2? If it belongs to mpich2 and Boost.MPI is built against openmpi, that may be the reason for your problem.

Comment: It seems mpic++ should be for OpenMPI: http://linux.die.net/man/1/mpic++ however typing mpic++ -show tells me it's linking against mpich2.

Comment: Just use dpkg or apt-file to check which package is actually installing that file. You must be sure that everything comes from one source (either MPICH2 or OpenMPI). Alternatively, assuming Boost.MPI uses OpenMPI, you could build OpenMPI from the sources and install it in some folder. Then using the mpic++ that you built and setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the subfolder where the libraries are will most probably solve your problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixing code compiled against different MPI libraries is not supported in general. If your Boost::MPI is linked against Open MPI, then you **must** use Open MPI for the rest of your application.

To get the `mpic++` as well as the other compiler wrappers and all the header files you should install the `-dev` package for Open MPI. If the library has been installed as a dependency then only the run-time part will be there.

Comment: lliev - How do you install the -dev package for Open MPI. Doing an apt-get install on the dev package gives me the 1.4 version of the package instead of the latest.